# UISplitViewController: how to go back from Detail to Master

Tags: ios, swift, segue, uisplitviewcontroller, master-detail

I am using a `UISplitViewController` to implement a Master/Detail flow app.

I am not using a Navigation Controller.

To go from the **MasterViewController** to the **DetailViewController** I am using:
`performSegueWithIdentifier("showDetail", sender: self)`

What should I use to go back from the **DetailViewController** to the **MasterViewController**?

Comment: You can just add a segue attached to a button back to the master view controller (if necessary) but why are you avoiding the navigation controller?  This situation is what it's built for.

Comment: I only have two viewcontrollers (each viewcontroller has as a containerview and tabs inside), so I don't really need a navigation controller. Yes, I would like to use a simple back button, but what is the exact code to attach to the back button?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a simple solution using the unwind action.

In the MasterControllerView I add the code:

```
@IBAction func backFromDetail(segue: UIStoryboardSegue) {
    print("back")
}
```

Using InterfaceBuilder, I create a custom Back button inside the DetailViewController, and I connect it to the Exit icon ([as explained here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12561735/what-are-unwind-segues-for-and-how-do-you-use-them)) selecting "backFromDetail".

After this, everything works magically! You just click on the custom Back button to go back to master.